# Fetching List Item Click

Tags: android

I have 2 activity in my app.

From First activity I take data to second activity's listview. In second activity I have a listview to show datas. Normally when I create a list and values myself I can create click event but now datas coming from other activity, and the datas uncertain.. How can I create click event for coming datas?(sorry for my very bad grammar)

It's my first activity;

```
Intent veri = new Intent(elementler.this,sonuclar.class);
veri.putStringArrayListExtra("logoveri", clickeddata);
startActivity(veri);
//I sent data for second activity's list
```

It's my list class;

```
//fetch values
Intent veri = getIntent();  
veriler = veri.getStringArrayListExtra("logoveri");
//there are a lot of possibility in "veriler" maybe user select banana              maybe apple maybe car maybe computer we can not know what he select..


//create a list with fetch data
ListView sonuclistesi=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.sonuclistesi);
ArrayAdapter<String> veriadaptoru=new Listeozellikleri(this,veriler);
sonuclistesi.setAdapter(veriadaptoru);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give listView onitem click,

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // do your stuff
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm new at android. Can you give detail? What can I do in "do your stuff"

Comment: Fine, from listView.setOnItemClickListener  while clicking any row u have to get that row position from that array & u can get value. Like, String name = veriler.get(position).toString();

Comment: Hope that will help u.